# receive values ​on the same line

Tags: ruby, uri

I need to receive three values ​​in the same line, and after multiplying two of those values, my program is stopping and returning zero after the third input.

```
code_product_1, units_product_1, price_product_1 = gets.split(' ')
code_product_2, units_product_2, price_product_2 = gets.split(' ')

total = (units_product_1.to_i * price_product_1.to_f) + (units_product_2.to_i * price_product_2.to_f)

puts "VALOR A PAGAR: R$ #{'%.2f' % total}"
```

**problem description:**

In this problem, the task is to read a code of a product 1, the number of units of product 1, the price for one unit of product 1, the code of a product 2, the number of units of product 2 and the price for one unit of product 2. After this, calculate and show the amount to be paid.

Input
The input file contains two lines of data. In each line there will be 3 values: two integers and a floating value with 2 digits after the decimal point.

Output
The output file must be a message like the following example where "Valor a pagar" means Value to Pay. Remember the space after ":" and after "R$" symbol. The value must be presented with 2 digits after the point.

**EDIT: INPUT AND OUTPUT SAMPLES**

Input Samples

- 12 - 1 - 5.30
- 16 - 2 - 5.10

Output Samples

- VALOR A PAGAR: R$ 15.50

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: can you edit your question and add the sample input file's data ?

Comment: @kiddorails I edited, was that input you are referring to?

Comment: Based on your input, I think your code should have `split(' - ') `

Comment: it doesn't work yet, it asks for two entries, and after the second one it returns a value that equals zero.
OUTPUT after 2 entries: *VALOR A PAGAR: R$ 0.00*

Comment: Worked for me. Can you add this line after line 2(after getting input) and edit the question with generated output: `p local_variables.each { |k| p [k, eval(k.to_s)] }`

Comment: You are doing it wrong. As per `Input The input file contains two lines of data. In each line there will be 3 values: two integers and a floating value with 2 digits after the decimal point.`, you should have been providing input to your script from file, whereas you are providing it incorrectly via stdin. - https://imgur.com/iryxSVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`total` is zero because some of the values collected from the user are `nil`.

For the calculation of `total` to be free of `nil`, you'll need to collect two pieces of data from the user that each can be `split` into three values.

Here's an example:

```rb
irb> code_product_1, units_product_1, price_product_1 = gets.split(' ')
1 2 3
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
irb> code_product_1
=> "1"
irb> units_product_1
=> "2"
irb> price_product_1
=> "3"
```

Do the same thing with your `_2` inputs, and then you can complete your total calculation.

*Note:* this doesn't include an input or output file. That's mentioned in the question but the code shared is asking for values from the user with `gets`.